# php-xlsxwriter: how to get a color in a row

Tags: php, format, styles

I have the follwoing code:

```
$writer->writeSheetHeader (Preisliste, $sheetheaders,
        ['auto_filter'=>true, 'widths'=>[20,35,12,40,15,8,8,10,13,13,13,13,13,13], 
        'font-style'=>'bold', 'fill'=>'#eee', 
        'freeze_rows'=>1, 
        'freeze_columns'=>0] );

$writer->writeSheetRow(Preisliste, $sheetrow);
```

Now I want to have a background color for example in the 3rd total row.
I do not find a solution.

Lookinf forward for help.
Thanx.

Comment: Rows don't have a color. Columns (cells) have.

Comment: you are right :-) ok. how can I format my code to get color in f.e. the third column

Comment: Never used that. But the repo has an [example](https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter/blob/master/examples/ex04-colors.php).